# Inheriting an overriden method from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, overriding

Imagine you have `abstract base class A`, and also 
`abstract class B` that inherites from `A` + overriding method of A named `foo()`

In addition, you have `concrete class C` which inherites from `B`

`C` has the overriden method `foo` inherited.
Now consider `method foo` is using reflection and iterates all over the class properties.

The question is : When `C.foo()` is lunched, the reflection will be done on `C Class` properties or on `B class` properties?
I need it to be done on properties from level `C` only.

Comment: Write the code and find out.  It's only a few lines of code.

Comment: If you reflect on C and invoke on C, it will be done on C just as normal invocation, aka on C properties. You can also just test it. The test should be 6 lines long or so.

Comment: Showing code for `foo` would be helpful - it is not possible to say what type's properties will be iterated without seeing how code is written.

Comment: The only way C.foo() can be called is on an object of type C.  So when you use this.GetType(), you'll see C members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose that your class *A* looks something similar to this.

```
abstract class A 
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    public abstract List<PropertyInfo> Foo();
}
```

Now, should your class *B* inherit from this class, and override the *Foo()* method, then it might look something like the following definition.

```
abstract class B : A
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public override List<PropertyInfo> Foo()
    {
        return GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Also, your last class, namely *C*, which is the only concrete class would then simply be defined as follows.

```
class C : B
{
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

In order to test this solution, and see that the only returned property is the **PropertyC**, you would need to run the following lines of code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new C().Foo().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`:

```
public override void Foo() {
    PropertyInfo[] piAry = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
}
```

Comment: Already did it :), the question is whether it will take properties from concrete class only, because implementation is on father base class